# MS Word VBA - Finding a word and changing its style

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm trying to find all instances of key words in a MS Word document and change their style. The key words are stored within an array and I want to change the style of the particular word only. Ideally this would happen as I type but that is not crucial.

Attempt 1 - Based on recording a macro and changing the search term

```
Sub Woohoo()
Dim mykeywords
mykeywords= Array("word1","word2","word3")

For myword= LBound(mykeywords) To UBound(mykeywords)

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyle")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = mykeywords(myword)
        .Replacement.Text = mykeywords(myword)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next

End Sub
```

This changes the style of the entire paragraph where the words are in.

Attempt 2 - Based on this question here [How can I replace a Microsoft Word character style within a range/selection in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748240/how-can-i-replace-a-microsoft-word-character-style-within-a-range-selection-in-v):

```
Sub FnR2()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mykeywords
mykeywords = Array("word1","word2","word3")

For nKey = LBound(mykeywords) To UBound(mykeywords)
For Each rng In ActiveDocument.Words
    If IsInArray(rng, mykeywords(nKey)) Then
        rng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyle")
    End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

This finds words that are in single lines but skips the words that are within a paragraph for some reason, e.g. it finds

```
Some text
word1
more text
```

but not

```
Some text before word1 means that the code above doesn't change the format
Word1 also isn't changed in this instance
```

Attempt 3 - AutoCorrect; not actually tried:

As an alternative I was thinking to use AutoCorrect. However I have more than 100 keywords and have no idea how to add this to the AutoCorrect list automatically (I'm fairly VBA illiterate). The other problem I would see with this approach is that I believe that AutoCorrect is global, whereas I need this only to work for a specific document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason why your macro isn't finding the words is due to the presence of leading or trailing blank spaces. Providing that you have already defined the style "NewStyle" changing your if statement in SubFnR2 from

```
If IsInArray(rng, mykeywords(nKey)) Then
```

to

```
If mykeywords(nkey) = LCase(Trim(rng.Text)) Then
```

Should solve the issue. By the way if you want to keep the style of the word depending on whether it is upper or lower case then remove the LCase part.

Edit:

I have included the sub with the modification below. I have tested it on the examples you gave (cut and pasted into word) and it changed the style for both instances word1.

```
Sub FnR3()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mykeywords
mykeywords = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")
Dim nkey As Integer

For nkey = LBound(mykeywords) To UBound(mykeywords)
For Each rng In ActiveDocument.Words

    If mykeywords(nkey) = LCase(Trim(rng.Text)) Then
        rng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyle")
    End If

Next rng
Next nkey

End Sub
```

Ok, your document behaves has you described, I'm not quite sure why. I checked selecting the range and just the word was selected, but then the whole paragraph was formatted. I have modified the code to modify the selection, shown below. This did just change the word.

```
Sub FnR4()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mykeywords
mykeywords = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")
Dim nkey As Integer

For nkey = LBound(mykeywords) To UBound(mykeywords)
    For Each rng In ActiveDocument.Words
        Selection.Collapse
        rng.Select
            If mykeywords(nkey) = LCase(Trim(rng.Text)) Then
                Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyle")
            End If

    Next rng
Next nkey

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Graham Anderson. I had a very quick go at this just now but it didn't seem to work. I might have mixed something up so I'll try again later on with a bit more time on my hands.

Comment: Could you describe what happened?

Comment: Thanks for copying in the snippet. Just tried it again and it now does find all instances. However, if I have something like this: `only word1 should be reformatted` it does apply the formatting to the entire sentence instead of only applying the format to `word1` itself. Maybe I try selecting the word first and the applying the format to the selection? Not sure if that would make more sense...

Comment: @pandita Are you using the sub as shown in the answer, I have tried copyiny only word one should be reformatted into word and running the macro. Only word1 was changed. In particular is `For Each rng In ActiveDocument.Words` used? Also what version of word are you using?

Comment: Yes, I copied it straight from the above and it does change the formatting of the entire paragraph. I tried it using MS Word 2007 running on Windows 7 as well as MS Word 2010 on Windows 8.... This is really strange... Without knowing much VBA, the code certainly looks like it should change the word itself only. Could it be a setting I have? Thanks for your help by the way @graham

Comment: @pandita Hmmnn... We are getting diferent results, could you try opening a new document typing in the text that doesn't work and running the macro on that document? Just want to see if it has something to do with the formatting of the document. If it doesn't work could you save the file in 2003 format and upload the document to a fileshare so I could see what's happening?

Comment: I should mention that the behavior at my PC is still as described above, i.e. the entire paragraph is reformatted rather than just the word. Thanks, @graham

Comment: @pandita I have downloaded the document and found that it behaved as described which was suprising considering similar tests I did didn't behave the same way. I have proposed a solution in the edited answer.

Comment: I'll take down the comment with the link to the file. To others: the missing comment was a test file in 2003 .doc format that demonstrated the problem with the original attempts

Comment: Tada! Works like a charm :) Thanks Graham

Comment: @pandita Your are welcome :) By the way I think I know why we were getting diferent results on the previous attempt. When creating a new style there is an option for style type, I had set this to character, the NewStyle in your document is set to paragraph and character.

Comment: yes that must have been it. Learned something new about VBA and MS Word! I've never paid notice to that before :)

Comment: Your code wroks great but one small caveat: It does apply the properties of the Style to the selected words BUT, when I click on any character of the modified word, it doesn't show them in the Style list as of that style...only the color and font as changed.  I need them to be of the "style" as an external application that is used by translation team need to look at style in Words.