# MS Word 2016 - Finding specific and changing its style using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to find specific words and apply a style to them in MS Word 2016.

Inspired by an older post: [MS Word VBA - Finding a word and changing its style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487483/ms-word-vba-finding-a-word-and-changing-its-style)

I created a style NewStyle with the 'Linked' Style type, which can be used as a character style. I ran the macro of the previously mentioned post:

```
Sub FnR4()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mykeywords
mykeywords = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")
Dim nkey As Integer

For nkey = LBound(mykeywords) To UBound(mykeywords)
For Each rng In ActiveDocument.Words
    Selection.Collapse
    rng.Select
        If mykeywords(nkey) = LCase(Trim(rng.Text)) Then
            Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyle")
        End If

Next rng
Next nkey

End Sub
```

When I run the macro, nothing happens... No idea what the problem is though!

Secondly, I'd prefer not to use an array, which is hard to edit. I'd like to point to a txt file which contains a word on each line.

Comment: HOW does it not work? Please be more specific. Use the [edit] link to put the information into the original Question. And a tip for asking questions on Stack Overflow: only ONE question in a "Question", please. If you have multiple questions that aren't closely related (and these are not) make separate questions. As it stands, your question should be closed on two counts: too broad and unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If you are applying a paragraph style, it will change the style for entire paragraph. If you want to apply a style to specific word, you need to apply character style. So, be specific on what is not working. Also, verify whether you already have a style called NewStyle in your document?

Comment: Thanks for the input! I edited my question:
* I added what doesn't work (nothing happens...)
* I have a style called NewStyle
* NewStyle is a 'linked' style, which can act as a paragraph style. I tried with a character style as well, same effect (nothing happens)

Answer (score 1):

Try something based on:

```
Sub BulkStyleUpdate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FRDoc As Document, FRList, i As Long
Set FRDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:="Drive:\FilePath\FindList.doc", ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
FRList = FRDoc.Range.Text
FRDoc.Close False
Set FRDoc = Nothing
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchCase = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(FRList, vbCr)) - 1
    .Text = Split(FRList, vbCr)(i)
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Style = "NewStyle"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Naturally, you'll need to supply the correct file details for the word list. The file format could be any valid format supported by Word.